# Shiny Error in :: argument of length 0 [No stack trace available]

Tags: r, module, shiny, stack-trace

I have the following error appearing when running R Shiny:

```
Warning: Error in :: argument of length 0
  [No stack trace available]
```

when I use the module in the application used in module R script it works without any error but when I use it in another module it does not work and bring the error that I have mentioned above

```
# first module
library(shiny)
UItrainTestSlider=function(id,data){
  ns=NS(id)
  tagList(
    sliderInput(inputId = ns("Slide"),label = "range data",min = 1,max = ifelse(is.null(data),2,nrow(data)),value=c(1,ifelse(is.null(data),2,nrow(data))),round = T)
  )
}
servertrainTestSlider=function(input,output,session,Data){
  data=reactive({
    Data()[input$Slide[1]:input$Slide[2],]
  })
  return(data)
}
```

when I run the following code it works

```
ui=fluidPage(
  UItrainTestSlider("foad",iris),
  verbatimTextOutput("txt")
)
server=function(input,output){
  data=callModule(servertrainTestSlider,"foad",reactive(iris))
  output$txt=renderPrint(data())
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

but when I put it into another module, it takes error

```
library(shiny)

UIinputPage=function(id){
  ns=NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
      h2("Data Input"),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = "train",
                 UIinput(ns("uitrain")),
                 uiOutput(ns("slidertrain")),
                 actionButton(ns("oktrain"),"submit train Data"),
                 verbatimTextOutput(ns("show"))
        ),
        tabPanel(title = "test",
                 UIinput(ns("uitest")),
                 htmlOutput(ns("slidertest")),
                 actionButton(ns("oktest"),"submit test Data")
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

serverInputPage=function(input,output,session){
  #newData to return
  Data=reactiveValues(train=NULL,
                      test=NULL)
  # train data #----
  DataTrain=reactiveVal()
  observe(
    DataTrain=callModule(serverInput,"uitrain")
  )

  output$slidertrain=renderUI(
    UItrainTestSlider("slider1",data = req(DataTrain$Value))
  )
  newTrainData=reactive({callModule(servertrainTestSlider,"slider1",Data=DataTrain$Value)})
  output$show=renderPrint(newTrainData())
  #----
  # test Data #----
  DataTest=callModule(serverInput,"uitest")
  output$slidertest=renderUI(
    UItrainTestSlider("slider2",data = req(DataTest$Value))
  )
  newTestData=reactive({callModule(servertrainTestSlider,"slider2",Data=DataTest$Value)})


  observeEvent(input$oktrain,ignoreNULL = T,{
    Data$train=req(newTestData(),cancelOutput = T)
    Data$test=req(newTestData(),cancelOutput = T)
  })

  observeEvent(input$oktest,ignoreNULL = T,{
    Data$train=req(newTestData(),cancelOutput = T)
    Data$test=req(newTestData(),cancelOutput = T)
  })
  return(Data)
}

# test #----
ui=fluidPage(
  UIinputPage("foad")
)

server=function(input,output){
  callModule(serverInputPage,"foad")
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

what should I have done to fix this error?